# Is priv.su/src.js virus or what?

Tags: javascript, security, virus

Almost in all website that i visit, when i inspect websites code i see this script:
`<script src="https://priv.su/src.js"></script>` in the  section.

I tried to google it, and there is little information about this. Some say that is a virus. Kaspersky antivirus is trying to block it.

Taking that SU is a russian domain, I'd believe that it is a threat.

Does anyone know what is this script, and what it does? Should i worry?

Thanks for Your help!

Comment: have you keep a copy of the file? i tried to access it but it gives ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, if i try to access from http i get 404.

Comment: After i wrote here about this, i cannot get it anymore, seems that something changed. On my side, i haven't changed a thing. I'll try to monitor a few days, maybe it will appear.